# how to text align center element inside legend

Tags: html, css

how to make the element inside the legend text align center?
[image]

here is my code..

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Event details</legend>

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Event title </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name ="eventTitle" value="<?=$title?>"readonly/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td><textarea style="resize:none" name="desc" rows="10" cols="40"><?=$desc?></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Venue Name</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name="venueName" value="<?=$venue?>"readonly/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Location</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="location" value="<?=$location?>"readonly/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Event Start Date</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="eventStartDate" value="<?=$eStart?>"readonly/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Event End Date</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="eventEndDate" value="<?=$eEnd?>"readonly/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Event Price</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="eventPrice" value="<?=$ePrice?>"readonly/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <button type="button">Update</button>

</fieldset>
```

i tried put margin auto in fieldset but still the same
and also i tried to put the textalign center in the table tag.

Comment: Do you want to align the form to center or the legend text?

Comment: the form to text aligh center

Comment: please try this. <legend style="margin:auto;">Event details</legend>

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by giving your `fieldset` element a `text-align` of `center` and setting your `table` element within to `display: inline-table`:

```css
fieldset {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Event details</legend>

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Event title </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name ="eventTitle" value="<?=$title?>"readonly/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td><textarea style="resize:none" name="desc" rows="10" cols="40"><?=$desc?></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Venue Name</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name="venueName" value="<?=$venue?>"readonly/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Location</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="location" value="<?=$location?>"readonly/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Event Start Date</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="eventStartDate" value="<?=$eStart?>"readonly/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Event End Date</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="eventEndDate" value="<?=$eEnd?>"readonly/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Event Price</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="eventPrice" value="<?=$ePrice?>"readonly/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <button type="button">Update</button>

</fieldset>
```

I wouldn't advise using a `<table>` here at all though really. Table elements are used to represent *tabular data*, not form fields.

Comment: What he should do is stop using tables for forms...

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Person:</legend>
Name: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
Date of birth: <input type="text" size="10" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Your CSS should look something like this:

```
legend {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**or**

```
<legend align="center">Legend</legend>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a table for form?!

Add a fix width to your table and `margin: 0 auto;`

```
table{
    width: 378px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/oog3kdwk/

**Or**

```
fieldset{
  text-align: center;
}

table{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/oog3kdwk/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
  <legend align="center" >Event details</legend>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your doubt, I advise you to make some changes in your HTML. The table tag should not be indented relative to legend tag, but as her brother. [Look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Examples).

What I did in this example, you were only centralize the label, but if you need to center the inputs, it is quite simple to add in CSS

```css
table tr td:first-child {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Event details</legend>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Event title</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="eventTitle" value="" readonly/>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="desc" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Venue Name</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="venueName" value="" readonly/>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Location</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="location" value="" readonly/>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Event Start Date</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="eventStartDate" value="" readonly/>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Event End Date</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="eventEndDate" value="" readonly/>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Event Price</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="eventPrice" value="" readonly/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button type="button">Update</button>
</fieldset>
```

I hope to have helped in some way

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS code for fieldset and legend to:

```
fieldset {
      display: block;
      margin: 20px 1%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: 0 auto;
      padding: 15px 0;
      border: 0;
      border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
      width: 98%;
}

fieldset:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 0px;
}

legend {
     display: table; 
     min-width: 0px;
     max-width: 70%;
     position: relative;
     margin: auto;
     padding: 5px 20px;
     color: #eee8aa;
     font-size: 20px;
     text-align: center;
}
```

then change

Event Details
        ...